# JSLint and assigning values with ternary expressions

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator, jslint

This is only an example, however with the below assignment using ternary expression, I can't get it to pass the [JSLint test](https://www.jslint.com).

Neither can I get it to ignore it.

```
var size = settings.size ? settings.size : defaults.size;
```

The error message is
"Wrap a ternary expression in parens, with a line break after the left paren."

What I can't find, is a way to use parens, and have the assignment still work.

Given there are about 10 of these, JSLint doesn't finish, and get to the really important stuff I want to check.

Comment: You can also save a few bytes by doing `var size = settings.size || defaults.size;`, though I'm not sure what JSLint would have to say about that.

Comment: This actually seems to remove any JSLint errors, although I had thought there was some reason for not doing x = A || B; however I can't recall it now.  This effectively answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this problem and found this post looking for the answer, but after some trial and error, I think I got it working.

This is the syntax I used to appease JSLint (using your example):

```
var size = (
  settings.size ? settings.size : defaults.size
);
```

This works as well:

```
var size = (
  settings.size ? settings.size : defaults.size);
```

Note that this particular ternary logic also causes JSLint to complain about something else: `Expected '||' and instead saw '?'`, but the above syntax does address the specific issue asked in the OP's question.

Comment: Whoa, that's ugly!

Comment: @Bergi was commenting based on an earlier version of my answer that had the close paren on the same line as the ternary. I also thought it was ugly, so I tried with the closed paren on a new line for more symmetrical formatting, and it still appeased JSLint and worked in browser. I still think this syntax looks weird, but I'm just using it to catch any JS bugs, as I assume the OP is as well. I might ditch this syntax before going to production.

Comment: Alternatively, ditch jslint with its weird rules :-)

Comment: Haha yeah, the thinking was JSLint could be a quick way to validate without a build system, but it struck me as odd that I couldn't find any documentation about this ternary formatting expectation. I'd never seen that before with other linters, but I am by no means a Javascript expert, so I would defer to people who know more about the subject.

Comment: FYI @JM-AGMS was correct in his comment on the OP's question. I don't have enough reputation to reply to his comment directly, but I updated my answer, as JSLint called out that issue as well. Good catch!

Comment: @bergi I tried the above, and whilst technically it's correct, as it removes the original error, it does, as you wrote, introduce a new one.  Therefore the x = A || B; answer is the best result.  I am using JSLint just to pull out any code errors, scope errors etc, and would ignore these errors, if it didn't mean it stops processing the rest of the code.  Any alternative to JSLint would be great.  I tried jsHint, however you just get a different set of weird errors...

Comment: @wcndave eslint is pretty much standard today, and highly configurable.

Comment: @Bergi  Thanks, never used it as it wasn't an online checker, and I didn't want to install all that locally.  However will give it a go.

Comment: @wcndave https://eslint.org/demo/ can be used online (but doesn't allow for custom rules)

Comment: @Bergi thanks for the eslint link! I'll start using that instead of JSLint.